# How to partially copy one QTextDocument to another with all of it's formatting

Tags: c++, qt, qtextdocument

I need to make a preview-version copy of very large QTextDocument (in rich text mode).
So, i need something like it's `clone()` function, but with ability to specifying the limit.
I.e. `clone (int maxChars)`.
As i understand from `clone()` source code, it just copy one document to another as single QTextDocumentFragment. So, i can't modify this process in the way i need.

Any ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you want to do the following:

1. Create `QTextCursor` with your `QTextDocument` as parent
2. Call `cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::Start)`. This will set cursor's position to the beginning of the document
3. Call `cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::NextWord, QTextCursor::KeepAnchor, n)`, where `n` is amount of words you want to be in your selection.
4. Call `cursor.selection()`. This method will return the selected `QTextDocumentFragment`.

Comment: Hmm, never even knew QTextCursor existed. Man, Qt has a class for almost everything. +1 for clarity and brevity.

Comment: I.e. you suggest word-by-word copying? i'm afraid only one thing - this code will work slow for text with complex formatting (my case). But i check this, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Axilles You can use `QTextCursor::Left` instead of `QTextCursor::NextWord`, if you need to move by specific number of characters.

Comment: @user2155932 So to select contents of my preview i need to call `cursor.movePosition (QTextCursor::Right, QTextCursor::MoveAnchor, MAX_CHARS)`?

Comment: @Axilles, yes, correct, `QTextCursor::Left` would actually move your cursor in incorrect direction =)

Comment: @user2155932 In Hebrew or Arabian language your advice will be correct. But i'm European :)

Answer (score 0):

If using rich text (specified via html markup) do the following:

```
// assuming some QTextDocument named 'source', return rich text as html QString object
QString html = source.toHtml();

// pass substring to new QTextDocument instance
QTextDocument dest(html.mid(startChar,endChar));
```

where startChar and endChar are integer indices of the html string from the source QTextDocument.

Comment: Because in this case i need to parse html to leave it valid (handle open and close tags, etc.).